# Is there a way to configure the initial Popover2 position when using auto placement?

Tags: blueprintjs

Currently the only supported auto option is `auto` and optionally suffixed with `-start` and `-end`. Is it possible to have something like `auto-bottom`? I imagine `-left` and `-right` would be nice as well. Maybe Blueprint is limited by the Popper.js library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of the Popper.js library.

I think the closest you can get is to set your desired position instead of using `auto` and then rely on modifiers to flip or reposition the popover if your desired position is not possible.